# Continuous map of a closed and bounded set

Tags: real-analysis

If $I$ is a closed and **bounded** interval such that $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, does a continuous function $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ exist such that $f(I)$ is closed and **unbounded**?

My attempt at an example was $I = (0,10]$ and the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ but I'm assuming I'm wrong because I made $I$ only half closed.

So I'm guessing the answer to the original question is "No" but I'm unsure.

Note: I need the function to be continuous but not necessarily uniformly continuous.

Comment: Continuous image of a compact set is compact. Also,  a subset of $\mathbb R^n $ is compact iff it's closed and bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO**. By using hiene borel theorem every closed and bounded subset of $\Bbb R $ is comapct . Image of compact set is compact if map is continuous. So image set is compact subset of $ \Bbb R $ i.e. closed and bounded